# Perform $lookup with object value in array from pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

So I have 3 models `user`, `property`, and `testimonials`.

Testimonials have a `propertyId`, `message` & `userId`. I've been able to get all the testimonials for each property with a pipeline.

```
Property.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId(propertyId) } },
  {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'propertytestimonials',
        let: { propPropertyId: '$_id' },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [{ $eq: ['$propertyId', '$$propPropertyId'] }],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        as: 'testimonials',
      },
    },
])
```

The returned property looks like this

```
{
 .... other property info,
 testimonials: [
  {
    _id: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f35',
    userId: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f29',
    message: 'Amazing property',
    propertyId: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f2f',
  },
  {
    _id: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f35',
    userId: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f34',
    message: 'Worth the price',
    propertyId: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f2f',
  },
 ]
}
```

User schema

```
firstName: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
lastName: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
email: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
```

Property schema

```
name: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
price: {
  type: Number,
  required: true,
},
location: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
```

Testimonial schema

```
propertyId: {
  type: ObjectId,
  required: true,
},
userId: {
  type: ObjectId,
  required: true,
},
testimonial: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
```

Now the question is how do I `$lookup` the `userId` from each testimonial so as to show the user's info and not just the id in each testimonial?

I want my response structured like this

```
{
    _id: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f34',
    name: 'Maisonette',
    price: 100000,
    testimonials: [
        {
            _id: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f35',
            userId: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f29',
            testimonial: 'Amazing property',
            propertyId: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f34',
            user: {
                _id: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f29',
                firstName: 'John',
                lastName: 'Doe',
                email: 'jd@mail.com',
            }
        },
        {
            _id: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f35',
            userId: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f27',
            testimonial: 'Worth the price',
            propertyId: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f34',
            user: {
                _id: '6124bbd2f8eacfa2ca662f27',
                firstName: 'Sam',
                lastName: 'Ben',
                email: 'sb@mail.com',
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: add the property schema

Comment: Show us the sample documents in all 3 collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `$lookup` stage inside pipeline,

- `$lookup` with users collection
- `$addFields`, `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from above user lookup result

```
Property.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId(propertyId) } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "propertytestimonials",
      let: { propPropertyId: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$propertyId", "$$propPropertyId"] }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "userId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user"
          }
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            user: { $arrayElemAt: ["$user", 0] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "testimonials"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CAUUJThb5mD)